# How to plot one single data point?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following code to plot a line and a point:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [3, 4, 6]})
point = pd.DataFrame({'x': [2], 'y': [5]})
ax = df.plot(x='x', y='y', label='line')
ax = point.plot(x='x', y='y', ax=ax, style='r-', label='point')
```

How do I get the single data point to show up?

[image: Plot with line and no point]

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. Does a plotting method for single data points even exist? if so, can you name it? thanks!

Comment: Peter, thanks for your question. I edited it to make it a reproducible minimal example. If possible, please try to do so in the future. I also removed the time-series and forecasting tags (this was not a modeling question), and added the pandas tag (since it involves plotting with `pandas`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When plotting a single data point, you cannot plot using lines. This is obvious when you think about it, because when plotting lines you actually plot *between* data points, and so if you only have one data point then you have nothing to connect your line to.

You can plot single data points using markers though, these are typically plotted directly on the data point and so it doesn't matter if you have only one data point.

At the moment you're using

```
ax = point.plot(x='x', y='y', ax=ax, style='r-', label='point')
```

to plot. This produces a red line (`r` for red, `-` for line). If you use the following code then you'll get blue crosses (`b` for blue, `x` for a cross).

```
ax = point.plot(x='x', y='y', ax=ax, style='bx', label='point')
```

`pandas` uses `matplotlib` internally for plotting, you can find the various style arguments in the tables [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot). To choose between the different styles (if, for example, you didn't want markers when you have multiple data points) then you could just check the length of the dataset and then use the appropriate style.

Comment: You also don't need to reassign `ax`.

Answer (score 117):

To plot a single point you can do something like this:

```
plt.plot([x], [y], marker='o', markersize=3, color="red")
```

Comment: Note: you can also omit the brackets.

Comment: I think part of what OP wants is to have the point also show up in the legend, given their use of the `label` argument in pandas plotting. Is there a way to do that here? In the new reproducible example, this doesn't work: `plt.plot(point['x'], point['y'], marker='o', markersize=3, color='red', label='point')`.

Comment: This removes the axes for a plot using a different set of points.

Answer (score 9):

Another **issue** that exists when using the `.plot(..)` method is that the **legend** is displayed with **lines** and **not dots**.
To fix this issue, I would recommend to use `plt.scatter(..)` as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [3, 4, 6]})
point = pd.DataFrame({'x': [2], 'y': [5]})

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 5))

# OP VERSION
df.plot('x', 'y', ax=axes[0], label='line')
point.plot('x', 'y', ax=axes[0], style='r-', label='point')

# MY VERSION
df.plot('x', 'y', ax=axes[1], label='line')
axes[1].scatter(point['x'], point['y'], marker='o', color='r', label='point')
axes[1].legend(loc='upper left')
```

I obtain this result, with on the left, OP's method, and on the right, my method:
[image: comparison_of_plot_methods]

Answer (score 1):

In the last line of the code in question, replace **style='-r'** with **kind='scatter'**:

```
ax = point.plot(x='x', y='y', ax=ax, kind='scatter', label='point')
```

[image]

You can optionally add a color argument to the call to point.plot:

```
ax = point.plot(x='x', y='y', ax=ax, kind='scatter', label='point', color='red')
```

[image]